# Gstreamer plugin is never called

Tags: python, plugins, gstreamer

How is it possible that the following Python Gstreamer plugin is correctly initialed, and that data flows through it (see attached pipeline) without printing anything besides the print in the `__init__` function?

```
import logging
import timeit
import math
import traceback
import time
import cv2

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstBase', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')

from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, GLib, GstBase, GstVideo  # noqa:F401,F402

from gstreamer.utils import gst_buffer_with_caps_to_ndarray


Gst.init(None)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class GstDropFrames(GstBase.BaseTransform):

    GST_PLUGIN_NAME = 'gstdropframes'

    __gstmetadata__ = (
        "GstDropFrames",
        "Transform",
        "Drop frames when the pipeline can't consume them all",
        "author"
    )

    __gsttemplates__ = (
        Gst.PadTemplate.new(
            "src",
            Gst.PadDirection.SRC,
            Gst.PadPresence.ALWAYS,
            Gst.Caps.new_any(),
        ),
        Gst.PadTemplate.new("sink",
            Gst.PadDirection.SINK,
            Gst.PadPresence.ALWAYS,
            Gst.Caps.new_any(),
        )
    )

    __gproperties__ = {}

    def __init__(self):
        super(GstDropFrames, self).__init__()
        print("PLUGIN Initialized GstDropFrames")

    def do_prepare_output_buffer(self, inbuf):
        print("PLUGIN do_prepare_output_buffer")
        buf = Gst.Buffer.new()
        buf.copy_into(inbuf, Gst.BufferCopyFlags.FLAGS | Gst.BufferCopyFlags.TIMESTAMPS |
            Gst.BufferCopyFlags.META | Gst.BufferCopyFlags.MEMORY, 0, inbuf.get_size())
        buf.pts = inbuf.pts
        return (Gst.FlowReturn.OK, buf)

    def do_transform(self, inbuf, outbuf):
        print("PLUGIN do_transform")
        # outbuf.copy_into(inbuf, Gst.BufferCopyFlags.FLAGS | Gst.BufferCopyFlags.TIMESTAMPS |
        #     Gst.BufferCopyFlags.META | Gst.BufferCopyFlags.MEMORY, 0, inbuf.get_size())
        return Gst.FlowReturn.OK

    def do_transform_ip(self, buffer: Gst.Buffer) -> Gst.FlowReturn:
        print("PLUGIN do_transform_ip")
        return Gst.FlowReturn.OK



# Register plugin to use it from command line
GObject.type_register(GstDropFrames)
__gstelementfactory__ = (
    GstDropFrames.GST_PLUGIN_NAME,
    Gst.Rank.NONE,
    GstDropFrames
)
```

Pipeline: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vu8DR1Puam14k-fUKVBW2bG1gN4AgSPm/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for the above issue if we create the custom Python plugin before any other element/plugin then the Python app works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).